# use jquery to change select price, echo price with php function

Tags: php, jquery, variables, select

I am creating a shopping cart and I am having trouble getting the jquery and php to work properly. I have a function called `displayAmount($price)` which at the moment just formats the number to 2 decimal points and adds the Pounds Sterling symbol to it. I would like to keep this function as in the future when I look at being able to allow the user to change their local currency, it will use this function to calculate and display the correct price and currency.

I want to be able to display a price on the view product page and have it change when the user changes the options in the select boxes.

So I have this:

jQuery:

```
$("select").live('change',function () {
      var price = 0;
      $("select option:selected").each(function () {
        price += parseFloat($(this).data('price'));
      });
      $('#productPriceLabel').html(price);
    });
```

HTML:

```
<select class='productSelectOptions'>
<option data-price='+10'>+10</option>
<option data-price='+20'>+20</option>
</select>
<br>
<span id='productPriceLabel'></span>
```

This works fine to change the price. However I need to be able to echo the price using `echo displayAmount($price)`

How can I do this?

Thanks

EDIT:

```
function displayAmount($amount)
    {
        $xamount = str_replace('.', '', $amount);
        $type = gettype($xamount);

        if($type = integer) {
            global $Config;
            return $Config['currency'] . number_format($amount, 2);
        } else {
            return $amount;
        }
    }
```

SECOND EDIT: (FULL CODE)

```
// Get prices from database
                    $priceSQL = "SELECT *
                                FROM shopProductsPrices
                                WHERE pd_id = '$productId'";    
                    $priceResult = dbQuery($priceSQL);
                    $priceOptions = "";
                    $productLowestPrice = 10500;
                    while($priceRow = dbFetch($priceResult)) {
                        if($productLowestPrice > $priceRow['spp_price']) { $productLowestPrice = $priceRow['spp_price']; }
                        $priceOptions .= "<option data-price='+".$priceRow['spp_price']."'>".$priceRow['spp_name']."</option>";
                    }
                    if($productLowestPrice == 10500) { $productLowestPrice = 0; }







<table style="border: none; width: 300px;">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <span id="productContentItem">Package:</span>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <select class='productSelectOptions'>
                                                            <?= $priceOptions ?>
                                                        </select>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <span id="productContentItem">Quantity:</span>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <select class='productSelectOptionsQty'>
                                                            <option value="1">x1</option>
                                                            <option value="2">x2</option>
                                                            <option value="3">x3</option>
                                                        </select>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <?= $productAddToBasket ?>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>

                                                        <span id='productPriceLabel'><?= displayAmount($productLowestPrice) ?></span>
<script>
    $(".productSelectOptions").live('change',function () {
      var price = 0;
      $(".productSelectOptions option:selected").each(function () {
        price += parseFloat($(this).data('price'));
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          dataType: "html",
          url: '<?= SERV_ROOT ?>library/common.php',
          data: '&price='+price,
          success: function(returnedData){
            $('#productPriceLabel').html(returnedData);
          },
          error: function(){
            $('#productPriceLabel').html('Error Formatting');
          }
        }); //END Ajax
      });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: post your php function here.

Comment: added to original post sorry

Comment: When you use jQuery, the interaction with your user is happening client side (within your user's browser). All PHP script is handled server side (in other words PHP is handled before the page is passed to the client). If you wish to have your user change a currency drop down on your page and have it reformat your pricing using your PHP script, you will need to use Ajax. See: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

If you would like, I can try to elaborate, but I can't as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I couldn't put in my comment:

I changed your "select on change" function to only execute when your "productSelectOptions" is changed. Otherwise, it would execute when ANY select option is changed. Was that what you wanted?

Here is the altered jQuery code that will send your new price to your PHP page to be formatted using your PHP function.

```
$(".productSelectOptions").live('change',function () {
  var price = 0;
  $(".productSelectOptions option:selected").each(function () {
    price += parseFloat($(this).data('price'));
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "html",
      url: 'formatdisplayAmount.php',
      data: '&price='+price,
      success: function(returnedData){
        $('#productPriceLabel').html(returnedData);
      },
      error: function(){
        $('#productPriceLabel').html('Error Formatting');
      }
    }); //END Ajax
  });

});
```

Your "formatdisplayAmount.php" would include your formatting function and look something like below:

```
function displayAmount($amount)
{
  $xamount = str_replace('.', '', $amount);
  $type = gettype($xamount);

  if($type = integer) {
    global $Config;
    return $Config['currency'] . number_format($amount, 2);
  } else {
    return $amount;
  }
}

echo displayAmount($_POST['price']);
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried this and it wouldnt work though. The price isn't passed through _POST?

Here is the URL of the page I am working on. Maybe that will help.

http://bitandpiecesvape.co.uk/site/?cid=28&pdid=82

EDIT: I also edited my original post to include the code as a whole, not including the php function which is currently the same as in your post.

Comment: So <?= SERV_ROOT ?>library/common.php is not receiving the $_POST variable "price" being sent via $.ajax? Could you add: `print_r($_POST);` on your common.php page and add `console.log(returnedData);` to the Ajax Success function and lemme know what your debug says?